# extjs4 apply filter just to showed grid data

Tags: grid, extjs4, filtering, store

First I have created this vaiable:

```
 var  filters = {
        ftype: 'filters',
        encode: false,
        local: true
    };
```

The code of the grid is like this:

```
{
                xtype: 'gridpanel',
                filterable: true,
                features: [filters],
                store: 'Webdesktop.store',
                columns: [
                {   
                    dataIndex: 'name',
                    text: 'my_text',
                    filter: { type: 'string'}  
                },
                ],
                viewConfig: {}
}
```

The problem is that in My_Grid I display just a part of my store's data, and when I want to filter a column, My_grid displays all store's data filtered.
For example:
my store contains this names: 'A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B2'
What I display in the grid: 'A1', 'B1'
when I begin to filter, I write 'A', the grid will display 'A1' and 'A2', but I want that the filter will be applied just to the showed data, and not to all the store's data!

Comment: Well this sounds a bit weird... do you have a filter applied? A grid will per default display all data within the store.

Comment: @sra: Yes I have a filter applied to the grid

Comment: Your first filter will be removed before the other get applied...

Comment: How can I make the first filter persist?